# Problems installing quantlib in python

Tags: python, quantlib

I'm trying to install `quantlib` in python, using `pycharm`. But I'm receiving this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QuantLib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for QuantLib

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

I've upgraded `pip`, but that was not the issue. I'm using python Python 3.7.16. I've even tried installing `QuantLib` python library available in `pypy` but the same result shows:

```
Collecting QuantLib-Python==1.18
  Using cached QuantLib_Python-1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 kB)

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QuantLib (from quantlib-python) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for QuantLib

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: macOS monterey M1 chip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like like @luigi-ballabio mentioned above : wheel for quantlib was not present for python 3.7 , arm architecture.

I was able to resolve this using the following steps :

Install Rosetta

Create a Rosetta terminal

Install X86 homebrew in the Rosetta terminal

Create an alias for the X86 homebrew in /usr/local/bin/brew

Use the X86 brew to install X86 python (ends up /usr/local/bin/python3)

Create a virtualenv based on the X86 python path

pip install quantlib

Comment: When you can, I do suggest upgrading to a newer version of Python, though.  Version 3.7 will reach end-of-life in June 2023, which means it will receive no more security patches after that.

Answer (score 1):

Wheels for M1 Macs are only available for Python 3.8 and above.  This seems to be a limitation of the tools provided by PyPA for building the wheels (see the table at https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel).